# Chrome : No data received, Safari : Can't open the page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web page which allow users to compose news articles. It has a rich text editor too. So someone can copy and paste text from the web. When I put some copied content from wiki to that and once I POST, it throws "No Data Received" error on Chrome. When I check this with Safari it says "Can't open the page". Firefox displays empty page.

But when I stop the execution of the mysql insert query it works fine. The issue is there is n issue with the mysql statement too. I extracted the generated sql statement and executed it separately with mysql tool. It works fine. No issue with the queries.

I am really stuck here. Could you please help me on this.

Thank you.

Prasad.

---

Here is the action code:

```
public function articlenewAction() { 
    $form = new Backoffice_Form_ArticleDraft(); 
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) { 
        $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost(); 
        if ($form->isValid($formData)) { 
            $postData = $_POST; 
            $newArticleID = Classes_Article::createArticle($postData); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: can you show use the code you are using?

Comment: Yes. Sure. It combined with several classes. However I will put the action code here.

public function articlenewAction(){

  $form = new Backoffice_Form_ArticleDraft();

  if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

   $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

   if ($form->isValid($formData)) {

    $postData = $_POST;

    $newArticleID = Classes_Article::createArticle($postData);

    
   }

  }

 }

Comment: I'm sorry this screen displays the code as mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we could go through this. We have upgraded the php version.

Let us know if you know any other way to fix this.

Prasad.